# Firebase Storage: this.xhr_.upload.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I'm having problems with the file upload. When I send a small file it works fine, but when it's a bigger file I get the error:

```
 this.xhr_.upload.addEventListener is not a function.
```

I'm working with vue.js and the npm package firebase 6.1.0.

I get this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: this.xhr_.upload.addEventListener is not a
 function
     at 
 NetworkXhrIo../node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm.js.NetworkXhrIo.addUploadProgressListener
```

I have tested with a basic code and still get the error on larger files. Like the docs:

```
 var uploadTask = storageRef.child(route).put(file);
```

Thanks!

Comment: For example, the error message is clear that the problem comes from `this.xhr_.upload`. But based on what you shared so far, we have no idea what `this`, `this.xhr_`, and `this.xhr_.upload` are.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using the firebase js sdk 6.1.0. this.xhr_.upload is called within the addUploadProgressListener function in the sdk. I think the shortest code to reproduce the error is in the question: var uploadTask = storageRef.child(route).put(file), and can be easily checked with the firebase sdk docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file . Thanks for your help!.

Comment: After 16 months any tip ?

Answer (score 1):

after thousand of time digging. I can solve this problem.
It's caused by some mocking API (For me is mockjs). You should try remove them all and firebase work fine!